# How to import the json file in neo4j to link the html code to a web page?

Tags: html, json, neo4j

I have tried to link the neo4j to the web page but the code does not run successfully. Has anyone done that before?is it because of the part where I try to import the json file into the neo4j database or is it due to other part of the code?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Visualization</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #viz {
        width: 900px;
        height: 700px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.neo4jlabs.com/neovis.js/v1.5.0/neovis.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    function draw() {
      var config = {
        container_id: "viz",
        server_url: "bolt://localhost:7687",
        server_user: "neo4j",
        server_password: "secret",
        labels: {
          Troll: {
            caption: "user_key",
            size: "pagerank",
            community: "community",
          },
        },
        relationships: {},
        initial_cypher:"call apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled1.json")
        yield value 
        unwind value.nodes as nodes 
        unwind nodes.properties as prop 
        with prop where prop.sourceIP is not null 
        with prop where prop.destIP is not null merge(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP})          
        merge(n2:Node{dest:prop.destIP}) 
        with prop,n1,n2 
        merge (n1)-[ :connected_to]->(n2) return n1,n2,prop",};
        var viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
        viz.render();
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="draw()">
    <div id="viz"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: so what I later did was to run the long query in the neo4j desktop and just run a simple query in the html: MATCH(n1)-[r:connected_to]->(n2) return n1,n2,r to get a glimpse of the graph.But it doesn't show the nodes' IP while the MATCH(n) RETURN n in neo4j will return all the nodes and their relationships.can anyone help?

Comment: The thing is that it shows the IP address when you hover your mouse over them. But I want to see them initially, any thoughts on how to solve the issue?